# Why is cast necessary for calling methods inherited from interfaces?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I was practicing to program for interface in java when I came across something I could not understand. Let me call the class Country

```
 class Country implements Comparable
    {
    int a; 
    int b; 
    int c;
    public Country(int _a,int _b,int _c)
    {
    a=_a;
    b=_b;
    c=_c;
    }
    public int compareTo(Object obj)
    {
    /*compares a, b and c and returns number of variables greater for this object.I am not include instanceof check*/
    int count=0;
    Country other=(Country)other;
    if(a>other.a)
    count++;
    else 
    if(a<other.a)
    count--;
    if(b>other.b)
    count++;
    else 
    if(b<other.b)
    count--;
    if(c>other.c)
    count++;
    else 
    if(c<other.c)
    count--;
    return count;
    }
public void write()
{
System.out.println(" hello");
}
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Object p=new Country(1,2,3);
    Object q=new Country(2,3,4);
    System.out.println(p.compareTo(q));
    }
    }
```

So the question here is if we declare something as

```
Object p=new Country(1,2,3);
Object q=new Country(2,3,4); 
p.write();
```

This works.
but why not

```
p.compareTo(q)//as done in the main code
```

Why is this cast required?

```
((Comparable)p).compareTo(q);
```

Comment: Note: You should be using `class Country implements Comparable<Country>`—avoid [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: `p.write(); ` does **not** work neither, at least for me. Not sure what you've done for it to work.

Comment: Also, I strongly doubt that your implementation of `compareTo` meets the [formal requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of the `Comparable` interface

Comment: @Slaw I do know about the generic interface but my question is about this one in particular.

Comment: @Andy Turner yes it does not because it does not follow x.compareTo(y)=-y.compareTo(x);

Comment: @Andy Turner yes i do not feel it is a duplicate . please request the removal of duplicacy.

Comment: @GhostCat yes the question of which has been a duplicate answers my question. Oh it is just so difficult to ask a non duplicate question.

Comment: @dawoodmansoor "Oh it is just so difficult to ask a non duplicate question" that means that you're not alone in things you find confusing :) It's sometimes hard to know what to search for, though, and those of us who have been around here for a long time can find it easily.

Comment: @AndyTurner I realized that when I saw the headings of the above questions. I will get used to it , god willing.

Comment: @lealceldeiro yes they answer it too. i have read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
Object p=new Country(1,2,3);
```

The compiler **could** know that `p` is of type Country. But it doesn't know it.

It only sees that you declared `p` to be of type `Object`. And the class Object does not have a `print()` method, or a `compareTo()` method.

Polymorphism (looking up methods on the actual type of objects) happens at runtime, but deciding whether some object **has** a specific method happens at compile time. And in this case, the compiler decides: `p` is an `Object`, thus it is missing the method you want to invoke!

Answer (score 2):

Because you are storing the value in a reference of type `Object`, so, the compiler has no way to know that it is actually a `Country` and that it implements `Comparable` at all.